# To whom Pind-daan is offered to - only male ancestors or both male and female ancestors?

Tags: rituals, death, ancestry

To whom Pind-daan is offered to - only male ancestors or both male and female ancestors i.e.
only to great......grand-fathers or to great.....grand-mothers as well?

Comment: To both male and females upto three generations. Which includes great grandparents, grandparents of both the sides from mother and father, and finally to own parents (if deceased).